# Convergence of sequence with open sets is the same with neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Usually convergence is defined using open sets, but I found that it can also be defined using neighborhoods, meaning

> $x_n\to x $ iff for all $V\in V(x)$, there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ s.t., if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in V$. $V(x)$ denotes the neighborhood of $x$.

I tried to prove the equivalence, but I'm stuck in the following direction:

$(\rightarrow)$

Let $V\in V(x)$. Then, there exists an open set $A$ s.t., $x\in A\subseteq V$. By hypothesis, there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ s.t., if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in A\subseteq V$. But from here, how do I get that $x_n\in V$?

The other direction I think I got it:

$(\leftarrow)$

Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$. Hence, $U\in V(x)$. By hypothesis, there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ s.t., if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in U$. So it holds.

Comment: if $x_n \in A \subseteq V$ whenever $n \geq N$ then $x_n \in V$ whenever $n \geq N$ as this is what is implied when an object is a member of a subset of $V$...

Comment: @MAPelto That's not true. Take $V=\Big\{A:=\{a,b,c\}\Big\}$. Then $a\in A\subseteq V$, but clearly $a\notin V$.

Comment: What I have said is true. And what you have said with your example is not true as $A \in V$ but $A \not\subseteq V$. There is a distinction between a subset and a member of a set of subsets.

Comment: "$V(x)$ denotes the neighborhood of $x$"? What is your definition of "neighborhood"? Usually "neighborhood of $x$" means either an open set containing $x$, or else, a superset of an open set containing $x$, depending on the author. In neither case does a neighborhood have other sets as members. One might call that "the family of neighborhoods of $x$", but not "the neighborhood of $x$".